# prediction from panel regression

Tags: data-visualization, interpretation, plm

My question is simple (code and data at the bottom): suppose I run panel data regression (fixed effects using first differences) and I want use the estimate to generate prediction for a given data (a country in this instance). I get nonsensical estimates as judging by the plot. why is that?

```
   dput(sub)
structure(list(Year = c(1999L, 1999L, 1999L, 1999L, 1999L, 1999L, 
1999L, 1999L, 1999L, 1999L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 
2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 
2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2003L, 2003L, 
2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2004L, 
2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 
2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 
2006L, 2006L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L
), Country = c("Algeria", "Argentina", "Australia", "Austria", 
"Azerbaijan", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Bolivia", "Bosnia.Herzegovina", 
"Brazil", "Algeria", "Argentina", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", 
"Belarus", "Belgium", "Bolivia", "Bosnia.Herzegovina", "Brazil", 
"Algeria", "Argentina", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", 
"Belarus", "Belgium", "Bolivia", "Bosnia.Herzegovina", "Brazil", 
"Algeria", "Argentina", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", 
"Belarus", "Belgium", "Bolivia", "Bosnia.Herzegovina", "Brazil", 
"Algeria", "Argentina", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", 
"Belarus", "Belgium", "Bolivia", "Bosnia.Herzegovina", "Brazil", 
"Algeria", "Argentina", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", 
"Belarus", "Belgium", "Bolivia", "Bosnia.Herzegovina", "Brazil", 
"Algeria", "Argentina", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", 
"Belarus", "Belgium", "Bolivia", "Bosnia.Herzegovina", "Brazil", 
"Algeria", "Argentina", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", 
"Belarus", "Belgium", "Bolivia", "Bosnia.Herzegovina", "Brazil", 
"Algeria", "Argentina", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", 
"Belarus", "Belgium", "Bolivia", "Bosnia.Herzegovina", "Brazil", 
"Algeria", "Argentina", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", 
"Belarus", "Belgium", "Bolivia", "Bosnia.Herzegovina", "Brazil", 
"Algeria", "Argentina", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", 
"Belarus", "Belgium", "Bolivia", "Bosnia.Herzegovina", "Brazil", 
"Algeria", "Argentina", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", 
"Belarus", "Belgium", "Bolivia", "Bosnia.Herzegovina", "Brazil", 
"Algeria", "Argentina", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", 
"Belarus", "Belgium", "Bolivia", "Bosnia.Herzegovina", "Brazil", 
"Algeria", "Argentina", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", 
"Belarus", "Belgium", "Bolivia", "Bosnia.Herzegovina", "Brazil", 
"Algeria", "Argentina", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", 
"Belarus", "Belgium", "Bolivia", "Bosnia.Herzegovina", "Brazil"
), Sales = c(95.8944381166513, 64.0106693324966, 42.2504490870201, 
68.592425399589, 47.3726360704271, 58.996097172436, 90.8021265007737, 
21.8177815583322, 38.3518087839097, 36.7467455599108, 99.0507025008208, 
62.7628018571842, 42.4573893769541, 68.8224145956935, 47.3695002869107, 
56.5993652769744, 91.4240669701777, 21.3225178274655, 38.7292600242417, 
36.0553845313843, 103.541156034684, 60.6099851013999, 43.0171814463866, 
69.0115998549256, 47.4679859817632, 51.6220934064619, 91.4313460021769, 
21.2606529949907, 38.8966168414042, 35.7122359917704, 108.939226106345, 
58.5347934982381, 43.4698699011516, 68.9214968650928, 47.2335224975754, 
49.0106571229537, 91.2497574481202, 21.6114367103643, 39.1724153943643, 
34.0436396876395, 114.308321673, 58.7653747686583, 44.0392412902328, 
68.8216679996652, 47.3181524670477, 48.2125173831955, 89.8752799421693, 
21.0723508892048, 39.395988019392, 31.6259789366501, 117.256143992851, 
64.8939773903886, 44.8838069920988, 68.6633810873396, 47.0980601080225, 
46.9185272950661, 88.0807037212701, 21.2459805651104, 40.1984860761948, 
32.0031356617173, 121.437908533661, 65.4026379699807, 45.5127217139869, 
68.0889954028725, 46.2074369557054, 46.4576606467326, 86.8220421465883, 
21.1636078981879, 41.3411370696666, 32.0673629640421, 126.448991635536, 
65.7436405286298, 45.6771928025734, 68.9134864065785, 45.0505760775497, 
45.3840369434857, 86.0891477265406, 21.0732163848255, 41.9675699286716, 
32.2652273191098, 131.928027755818, 66.1334267456321, 46.0695839419414, 
69.7600017214328, 44.6745925825115, 44.2851316505321, 86.2851189110147, 
21.2211033412504, 42.062182989799, 32.2889585183012, 132.821502964114, 
66.1845285004542, 46.157575971183, 70.6254004358242, 44.6126031838785, 
44.0273505963435, 86.2101884510124, 20.7446249745022, 41.5842166506861, 
32.665638806492, 134.573064031085, 64.1017799644877, 46.5957739430383, 
70.9028046285705, 43.4507072071856, 42.1794624439168, 85.8055862883346, 
20.6095110207347, 41.0824996979067, 32.7791402456364, 136.284506722069, 
65.0592996672527, 46.8998026198699, 70.9768842082468, 41.8262387944699, 
40.2355864426294, 85.3238024060506, 20.7615996980417, 41.1965490971463, 
33.1416588120605, 137.622225499504, 68.175300014101, 48.9467164949536, 
70.9863339371377, 40.4478762909068, 40.7964999971242, 84.4801890900119, 
20.9070660674925, 40.2851449093038, 33.0710446928608, 139.064684223893, 
72.9884630999702, 48.8084240171217, 70.9010985906014, 41.0786112413501, 
41.2941384670262, 84.1084847341722, 21.0670923852576, 38.5175453440777, 
33.1192642704409, 140.542567157515, 75.011469793228, 49.2059152143781, 
70.8404674413569, 41.5029961541057, 40.7974494691671, 83.6438518401962, 
21.1956638958654, 38.0133387510644, 33.2596125735965), EXP = c(1163.46584289649, 
4144.48381297637, 29186.5662291083, 24485.6826484965, 1029.88305529711, 
977.75097160833, 21677.0761126763, 1345.27472347896, 2409.62367573159, 
4408.56326407276, 1175.69749838433, 4096.57168780594, 29491.8061250808, 
25084.931692415, 1057.92005203665, 1061.73195101225, 22401.5253218427, 
1353.45325431479, 2931.54926680318, 4465.49186258371, 1198.7142516671, 
3856.02643560489, 29765.8192759168, 25127.8821101651, 1111.78499944542, 
1213.04616790704, 22529.9533274211, 1336.70383046062, 3114.96309355026, 
4498.77440809212, 1251.91944633789, 3150.65583495807, 30570.9719410864, 
25029.2448943653, 1259.28231926166, 1358.69738495414, 22426.684892177, 
1344.25136113266, 3431.19902957306, 4517.29953517672, 1264.74147242314, 
3359.19617225233, 31252.3329396919, 25258.843559964, 1382.37326464471, 
1469.80196425483, 22434.7577754165, 1328.41678188448, 3546.45318742496, 
4501.21926163389, 1336.69977461448, 3783.19769358879, 32316.4540680267, 
25646.8574368323, 1424.27353008109, 1605.94093600197, 22742.4520803842, 
1342.42070254017, 3578.36558161303, 4593.15937903318, 1397.8741457221, 
4118.9831492705, 32735.578506296, 26130.8268666205, 1419.46848261003, 
1851.23892137149, 22833.7608555051, 1356.27214539086, 3792.95060652715, 
4722.42226184219, 1423.48396353205, 4503.07392530465, 33525.038482202, 
26575.1376313285, 1714.46576562884, 2096.38713137564, 23372.6397442315, 
1423.55900720559, 3891.14156116222, 4945.40684244658, 1486.46132250634, 
5160.31813196005, 35110.0491788707, 26818.4888320441, 1984.86500501956, 
2411.82602849836, 23839.6439276401, 1460.50368695631, 4106.95573926962, 
5278.38404649135, 1571.47761004493, 5957.35230671835, 34761.2425247588, 
26785.3759746842, 2293.68442123487, 2843.12902938464, 23838.6801802891, 
1454.35691928422, 4268.32282042517, 5541.66622624175, 1642.83499123667, 
6302.46425644749, 34691.9755570142, 26674.8208912709, 2536.06453868914, 
2869.75286326942, 23608.1584997043, 1467.71290479986, 4115.07776018614, 
5797.6448321436, 1707.32444249791, 7129.54471669768, 34912.7956874583, 
27141.0490144222, 2600.14034853739, 3150.45727578947, 23975.3410200551, 
1519.02983116863, 4097.64427116637, 6203.32572966466, 1779.3218357667, 
8083.52794968159, 35226.8781804712, 27392.5299598346, 2768.72771125331, 
3266.95435282454, 23559.6391136587, 1603.53956956052, 4055.07855858022, 
6417.45227136566, 1846.10734803661, 8895.67097544672, 35735.0319349191, 
27436.1920938698, 2984.97062836353, 3430.50036396676, 23176.6945474702, 
1660.39571168814, 4044.27166071046, 6632.30041874543, 1898.06871845183, 
9758.01468255447, 35841.3486896582, 27329.9772262359, 3271.5659201921, 
3838.59673154276, 23228.0537576819, 1766.4915870787, 4084.04073243139, 
6826.13674728869), predict = c(450.238415301409, 4952.25418216149, 
481112.505419658, 274187.843235333, 365.559323711714, 378.332366977019, 
203106.100512995, 580.932725477942, 1916.72468814091, 5615.53850037917, 
458.900305452595, 5465.68031633326, 436603.595009786, 291412.391258709, 
432.501953419384, 384.680357737652, 220363.751586866, 663.630690745511, 
2475.38189288867, 5771.29893671362, 536.393688050585, 4272.4806068803, 
447337.921496059, 330751.708405389, 416.28875243834, 484.524127389951, 
252573.838385904, 573.873910884966, 2791.51452400908, 6623.24460916918, 
511.462744878348, 2855.00403248772, 540879.765627226, 289536.318355925, 
517.222948996678, 668.185033031338, 220764.790936325, 580.152291637416, 
3822.22508699283, 5904.68216878707, 521.155361560103, 3663.99001182773, 
505607.930466389, 296458.377207048, 688.945806517349, 679.293998356651, 
221167.630033733, 642.107397960161, 3609.6076672122, 5866.90477283123, 
649.187865184038, 4110.85481377508, 551042.074078385, 348001.559877222, 
642.203047112371, 797.409309630497, 258471.522833888, 578.214359379061, 
3678.49082944877, 6913.41846193664, 621.187921168909, 4890.24028347256, 
643562.245277392, 322295.899542789, 638.95085863757, 1168.5421992858, 
230748.002085899, 589.353500308812, 4674.63316779749, 6472.91853096103, 
642.171985392394, 6636.30802669053, 604570.571955646, 336464.609459538, 
1014.98852065657, 1301.82390426973, 244626.944891584, 725.839446586913, 
4351.67225138151, 7131.62335055538, 784.10500092416, 7787.7345327038, 
681127.266843129, 389028.716117371, 1175.40851837317, 1698.9044302329, 
290313.126068481, 671.631440999589, 4861.14559078558, 9238.23799112805, 
766.029560460583, 10560.2443726489, 750332.619751713, 342834.041552497, 
1543.99973842967, 2637.61337751398, 256606.139338914, 667.216872427894, 
5944.48810030743, 9048.76903116735, 830.928516274965, 13462.3377462398, 
659897.937031688, 339626.843417475, 2114.03217129097, 2374.39699776711, 
250755.294305202, 766.495234681433, 4876.20143177577, 9966.86419251035, 
1007.28375557442, 15533.0081117901, 671352.348040235, 400840.676085997, 
1960.72608400337, 2854.64864122412, 294415.455157649, 720.612675595252, 
4838.68864424432, 13012.5378940013, 960.33985405504, 20471.6413216694, 
776389.882461728, 362615.96374989, 2216.37020252625, 3466.72984599584, 
249250.758616235, 795.252604552861, 5353.42736643621, 12371.6264585595, 
1028.66108049217, 28610.2420611794, 712036.960902431, 364407.986385188, 
2901.14187067088, 3377.40762532449, 239601.473856572, 957.418871088998, 
4706.68469357758, 13293.4064973186, 1223.75276094355, 31118.52049929, 
718170.301207394, 407864.36799513, 3073.11901352917, 4237.45556639294, 
272274.784059483, 947.67605070943, 4805.98654235499, 15989.1113027794
)), .Names = c("Year", "Country", "Sales", "EXP", "predict"), row.names = c(NA, 
-150L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

fit <- plm(data = sub, log(Sales) ~ log(EXP) + I(log(Sales)^2), index = c("Country", "Year"), model = "fd", effect = "individual")

sub[, predict := exp(coef(fit) + coef(fit)[[2]] * log(EXP) + coef(fit)[[3]] * log(EXP)^2)]

ggplot(sub, aes(x = Year, y = Sales, colour = Country)) + geom_line() + theme(legend.position = "none") + 
  geom_line(data = sub[Country == "Algeria"], colour = "black") + 
  geom_line(data = sub[Country == "Algeria"], aes(y = predict), colour = "red", size = 1)
```

Comment: Your regression coefficients are for first differences, but you're comparing those to data that hasn't been differenced. Take the first difference of log(Sales), log(EXP), etc., compare your results to the first difference of log(Sales) and it should work.

Comment: @j-kahn - interesting. I don't get this thing: basically the model is `log(y) ~ log(x) + log(x)^2` and I thought that the first differences are just the estimation equation. that is - the parameter estimates carry the interpretation over to the initial model which could be use for prediction. but then your suggestions hints that I could only interpret the coefficients in the context of first differences rather than the initial model?

Comment: Sort of. I'm just going to go ahead and answer this below because I need tex to explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way this particular `plm` estimator works is to start with a model like:

$$y_{i,t}=\gamma_i + \alpha \times t +x_{i,t}^\prime\beta + \varepsilon_{i,t}$$

and remove the fixed effect by first differencing:

$$\Delta y_{i,t} = \alpha + \Delta x_{i,t}^\prime\beta$$

your estimates in `fit` correspond to this $\alpha$ and $\beta$. So it only makes sense to compare these to the *difference* in your dependent variable. In fact, depending on your assumptions this may be the most direct way to compare your model to the data (especially if the trend in your variables is large).

If you want to get fitted values for $y_{i,t}$ not $\Delta y_{i,t}$, you first need to come up with an estimate of $\gamma_{i}$ and calculate:

$$\hat{y}_{i,t} = \hat{\gamma}_i + \hat{\alpha} t + \Delta x^\prime_{i,t}\hat{\beta}$$

though again this may make *less* sense in assessing model fit. *Technically* the asymptotics for this model consider $N\to\infty$ instead of $T\to\infty$, so $\hat{\gamma}_i$ isn't available. However, `plm` does have estimates for fixed effects from the `fe` model under `plm`. I also don't think it's uncommon to cheat and assume that the first observation is measured without error and just add the difference estimates to it. How much that matters depends in part on how large your first $y$ value is relative to the differences that occur over time.